# How can we unit-test code which uses Google Cloud Storage underneath?

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-storage, pytest

I am working on a simple service which primarily converts files into different formats. After conversion, I want to upload the result to a GCS bucketl

Here is what that might look like:

```py
def convert_and_upload_files(files: List[str], bucket: Bucket) -> str:

    new_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    tmp = TemporaryDirectory()
    tmp_dir = tmp.name

    try:

        # Convert files locally 
        converter.convert(files, out_dir=tmp_dir)

        # Upload all converted files to the bucket
        upload_directory(bucket, directory=tmp_dir, out_dir=new_id)

    finally:
        # Clean up
        shutil.rmtree(tmp.name)

    return new_id
```

How can I test something like this locally, without requiring actual GCS credentials?

I have been looking around and found [`cloudstorage_test.py`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/8e5c9d5d89688b4beab6f8713da79f176012e82d/python/test/cloudstorage_test.py) on GitHub, but these examples would require me to leave convenvience land and install the SDK. Besides that, I kind of feel that this should not be this complicated to I might be missing something.

I know e.g. that with Firebase we have a [Cloud Storage Emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_storage).

So, how can we run unit-test code that uses GCS underneath?

Comment: For local unit testing using GCS, it seems the current libraries [support using](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) an emulator. Have you tested whether the Firebase Cloud Storage emulator works with this? In any case, there seems to be this standalone [emulator library](https://github.com/oittaa/gcp-storage-emulator) for GCS, and it offers details on how to set the GCS Python library to connect to it rather than an actual bucket.

Comment: Were you able to test whether the third party emulator worked for your use case?